# Part's of form not being rendered - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I can't seem to find why the "start" and "finish" part of my form isn't being rendered. This is the first time I've ever worked with AngularJS, and after following quite a few tuts online, I used to yo meanjs generator with the articles example. I then took the articles example and tried to port it over to this scheduling thing. It really doesn't matter though, I just want to know why the last two inputs in the form aren't being rendered in my view.

Any help is much appreciated

Here's the code for my view:

```
<section data-ng-controller="SchedulesController">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>New Schedule</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form name="scheduleForm" class="form-horizontal" data-ng-submit="create()" novalidate>
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ "has-error": scheduleForm.title.$dirty && scheduleForm.title.$invalid }">
                    <label class="control-label" for="title">Title</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="title" type="text" data-ng-model="title" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="content">Content</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea name="content" data-ng-model="content" id="content" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="start">Start</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="finish" value="" type="date" data-ng-model="start" class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="finish">Finish</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input name="finish" value ="" type="date" data-ng-model="finish", class="form-control" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                </div>
                <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-danger">
                    <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's the code for my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('schedules').controller('SchedulesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Schedules',
    function($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, Schedules) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;

        $scope.create = function() {
            var schedule = new Schedules({
                title: this.title,
                content: this.content,
                start: this.start,
                finish: this.finish
            });
            schedule.$save(function(response) {
                $location.path('schedules/' + response._id);
                console.log('hola!');
                $scope.title = '';
                $scope.content = '';
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };

        $scope.remove = function(schedule) {
            if (schedule) {
                schedule.$remove();

                for (var i in $scope.schedules) {
                    if ($scope.schedules[i] === schedule) {
                        $scope.schedules.splice(i, 1);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $scope.schedule.$remove(function() {
                    $location.path('schedules');
                });
            }
        };

        $scope.update = function() {
            var schedule = $scope.schedule;

            schedule.$update(function() {
                $location.path('schedules/' + schedule._id);
            }, function(errorResponse) {
                $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
            });
        };

        $scope.find = function() {
            $scope.schedules = Schedules.query();
        };

        $scope.findOne = function() {
            $scope.schedule = Schedules.get({
                scheduleId: $stateParams.scheduleId
            });
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xhuuL5qg/ I dropped this into a jsfiddle, and the code seems to run. What errors do you get in the console? It appears that their must be some other part of your app that is blocking the loading of this form.

Answer (score 0):

Um... Well guys.... I don't know WHY this worked, and everything in me tells me this wasn't the problem, BUT:

Notice line
`<input name="finish" value ="" type="date" data-ng-model="finish", class="form-control" required>`

The "," was a mistake (I wrote a script that ported everything from articles into schedule, maintining code structure and just changing all mentions of [Aa]rticle{s} -> [Ss]chedule{s}, and this was left over in that (for some reason, don't know where it came in). Anyway, I deleted the comment and ran `grunt build && grunt test && grunt` and it worked. I'm now getting the correct render.